# Aloha editor slow pasting

Tags: javascript, performance, paste, aloha-editor

I'm using Aloha Editor in a Ruby on Rails application for my client, and i have many issues with the pasting plugin.

Copying text from a webpage or MS Word, and i pasting it makes the script freeze, and Firefox tells me that "the script is not responding".

It doesn't happen when i paste a single line of text.

This is my configuration file for Aloha : http://pastie.org/private/uhffpep12x53p27d1zibqg

Do you know how I can solve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: is there any difference regarding the freezing script when you deactivate the formatlesspaste plugin?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't change anything...

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  I'm using locomotivecms which depends on Aloha for editing the sites content.  I'm using chrome and it does the same thing.  If I paste from sublimeText it works but if I paste from word or anything else it freezes the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution of this issue. It was due to a misconception of my HTML tags.
I replaced :

```
%p.editable-long-text
```

by

```
%div.editable-long-text
```

And now it works perfectly !